# Unity launcher about:config does not show anything

Tags: 11.04, unity

I wanted to change the launcher size on ubuntu 11.04.

I pressed super(win) key, and typed `about:config`, selected the Unity icon, but nothing happened. After that, I tried the same again, but this time the unity icon doesnt even appear in the result. what might be wrong?

Comment: where did you read about `about:config`? I only heard about it from you just now; pretty cool (see answer below: it has to be from alt-f2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing `about:config` from the "Super" menu doesn't run the plugin.  You can run it by pressing Alt+F2, then typing `about:config`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. That was so stupid of me for doing it on Super, instead of ALT F2